# Comparison operator for ranges C++

Tags: c++, overloading

If you want to lexicographically compare two vectors in C++, you can simply write `vec1 <=> vec2`. But instead, if you want to compare them reversed, it is not as simple as writing `(vec1 | std::views::reverse) <=> (vec2 | std::views::reverse)`. So, I decided to write comparison operators for ranges in C++.

This is what I came up with:

```
inline constexpr auto operator==(const std::ranges::range auto& range1,
                                 const std::ranges::range auto& range2)
  -> decltype(begin(range1) == begin(range2)) {
    return std::equal(
      begin(range1), end(range1), begin(range2), end(range2));
}

inline constexpr auto operator<=>(const std::ranges::range auto& range1,
                                  const std::ranges::range auto& range2)
  -> decltype(begin(range1) <=> begin(range2)) {
    return std::lexicographical_compare_three_way(
      begin(range1), end(range1), begin(range2), end(range2));
}
```

Are the above functions correct?

These are currently generating other equality and comparison operators synthetically. But should I explicitly declare them as defaulted? If want to do so, how?

The unqualified names `begin`, `end` in above code are calling functions in `std::` namespace or `std::ranges::` namespace? Should I explicitly prefix them with `std::ranges::` namespace.

Should I put these in their own namespace? If I do so, then I have to explicitly write `using namespace rangecomp;`, since these are not being detected by even ADL. So what to do?

Comment: This isn’t so much a review of your code, but: when I think of "comparing ranges," I’m almost always blending two different ranges based on a predicate. That’s also what those operators mean for [GCC vector extensions.](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html) So this notation will be very ambiguous.

Comment: @Davislor You meant element-wise comparisons? Yeah, that's a good point. But STL containers already have lexicographical comparison operators. I'm just extending that to ranges. Nonetheless, it's an opinionated decision.

Comment: @Davislor Actually there is `std::valarray` which does element-wise comparisons. But I'm not sure I can distinguish a range originated from valarray and that originated from vector. If you have any ideas, please tell me.

Comment: I remember one keynote lecture where the speaker showed an overloaded `*` operator for vectors and asked, is this code intuitive and obvious? How many of you think it means dot product? How many of you think it’s element-wise multiplication? Whenever he asks, half the people think it’s one, half the other, but they all think it’s obvious. Same with `+` meaning element-wise addition or concatenation.

Comment: Ranges inherently can’t have the kind of memory-alignment requirements that `valarray` does, to allow maximum SIMD optimization. However, you could derive a subclass of `std::span` or `std::ranges::subrange` that implements element-wise operations, and document, these operators are element-wise. You would probably want to implement them using expression templates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does seem quite bold to provide these operators as such wide-ranging templates, which match all ranges.  Not necessarily wrong, but it makes me slightly nervous of unintended side-effects!

I do think we should at least be constraining to accept only *input* ranges, as `std::equal()` and `std::lexicographical_compare_three_way()` require.

I don't think we need to be writing the return types, as plain `auto` is fine here - both `std::equal()` and `std::lexicographical_compare_three_way()` return the types we want. Not doing so avoids us needing to write unqualified `begin` and `end` - we can make the `using`s local to the functions, rather than polluting global namespace.

If we're providing `==`, we should also provide `!=`.  We can't use `= default`, because it's a template, and if we leave it undefined, it will be synthesised from `<=>` rather than from `==`.

---

## Modified code

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <ranges>

inline constexpr auto operator==(const std::ranges::input_range auto& range1,
                                 const std::ranges::input_range auto& range2)
{
    using std::ranges::begin;
    using std::ranges::end;

    return std::equal(begin(range1), end(range1),
                      begin(range2), end(range2));
}

inline constexpr auto operator!=(const std::ranges::input_range auto& range1,
                                 const std::ranges::input_range auto& range2)
{
    return !(range1 == range2);
}

inline constexpr auto operator<=>(const std::ranges::input_range auto& range1,
                                  const std::ranges::input_range auto& range2)
{
    using std::ranges::begin;
    using std::ranges::end;

    return std::lexicographical_compare_three_way(begin(range1), end(range1),
                                                  begin(range2), end(range2));
}
```

```
#include <array>
#include <vector>
int main()
{
    int const a[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    auto const v = std::vector{ 1, 2, 3 };
    auto const vr = std::vector{ 3, 2, 1 };

    return false
        | ((a | std::views::all) <=> a) != std::strong_ordering::equivalent
        | (a | std::views::reverse) != ( v | std::views::reverse)
        | (v | std::views::reverse) != vr
        | !(a == v)
        | (a <=> v) != std::strong_ordering::equivalent
        | v < a
        | v > a
        ;
}
```

---

## Answers to questions

The functions seem reasonable, though `std::ranges::equal()` might make a better choice for the first (there's no `std::ranges::lexicographical_compare_three_way` yet, due to the algorithm arriving at the same time as Ranges).

We can't default the other comparison operators because they are templates.  We could write them all, but I think it's better to let the compiler default them.

Don't inhibit ADL by calling `std::ranges::begin` specifically - have `using` within the function as shown.  (I might be wrong here, as niebloids have special ADL behaviour).

Yes, declare a namespace, but don't `using namespace` *unless* the comparisons are the only things in that namespace.  Client code should just alias the specific names needed, and in the smallest reasonable scope (e.g. `using my_comparators::operator<=>;`).    Enclosing in a namespace allows applications greater control over which parts of their code will match these very broad templates.

The functions should be detected by ADL - unless the view types you are using are not in that namespace (e.g. the standard view adapters in `std::ranges::views`).  If you can create a minimal example of ADL failing for non-niebloid types in the same namespace, that would make a good question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I provided these operators as for all ranges since almost all (except span and mdspan) strictly ordered containers in the STL already provide these operators. So I thought any ranges on those can also benefit from these operators.

Comment: If we are providing `==`, then compiler can generate `!=` automatically, similar to other comparison operators. Why you think we need to specify it explicitly?

Comment: It's sad that they didn't add `std::ranges::lexicographical_compare_three_way` even in C++23. As you might have guessed, I used `std::equal` instead of `std::ranges::equal` just to keep them symmetrical.

Comment: "Don't inhibit ADL by calling std::ranges::begin specifically - have using within the function as shown." I didn't get this. If I'm correct, when I write just `begin(range1)`, wouldn't this cause `std::ranges::begin` to be invoked since it is a niebloid?

Comment: "unless the view types are not in that namespace." Since I will be using these operators with std ranges, isn't it always the case that 'the view types are not in that namespace'? Or you meant something else by that?

Comment: It wasn't clear whether you'd only be using standard ranges and views, or whether you'd be mainly providing your own.  So I worded that to cover all cases.

Comment: Compilers can generate `!=` from `==`, but that's not automatic.  Without that definition, `!=` will be synthesized from `<=>` (and we can't just write `= default`, as that's not valid for template functions).  Actually, it's probably sufficient just to provide `<=>` and let everything else be synthesized from it.

Comment: I can't remember ADL rules for niebloids, so I may very well be wrong there.

Comment: Actually, when I tried, `!=` was invoking `==` without writing `= default`. I tried on GCC 12.2.